# Why is MySQL result being truncated?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

I have tried to get increase my column size in java using the below:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Column(length=65534)
private String queryData;
```

and have tried to increase my cache size in MySQL like so:

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 1;
SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 256000000;
SET GLOBAL query_cache_min_res_unit = 2000000;
SET GLOBAL query_cache_limit = 2000000;
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

but still it returns a string of size 32767 characters.

Comment: You should alter the table and increase the length of the column

Comment: which db version your are using  and which datatype  ??? check for your column definition

Comment: The data in the database is okay. Even when I query in MySQL workbench nothing is missing. It's only when my Java is involved things start to fall apart.

Comment: @scaisEdge I'm using MySQL with mediumtext as datatype. I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: and which version of mysql ??.. and which collation  .too??